# Latex merging commands

Tags: macros, alignment

I defined a `\longName` command: `\newcommand*\longName[1]{\raggedright {\sloppy \textbf{#1}}}` But after I call it, it mess up the below text, that text become ragged right as well, and I do not want it. I only want to rangged right that particular text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\doublespacing

\newcommand*\longName[1]{\raggedright {\sloppy \textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\longName{Long name containing several hyphens, and multiple lines}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\newline


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need

```
\newcommand*\longName[1]{\par{\raggedright\textbf{#1}\par}}
```

with `\raggedright` inside the group to control its scope, and `\par` inside the group so the paragraph ends within that scope. There is not much use for `\sloppy` in a ragged setting, so I removed that.